# How can I safely walk through Electric water in DX:HR?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In DX:HR there are certain places in levels, where there is electricity running on the ground, over water puddles or something.

Is there any way I can walk through it, or do I have to bypass it every time?
Or is there a certain augmentation that I need?

Comment: with rubber boots ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **EMP Shielding** augmentation will protect you from electric shock (and EMP grenades, etc).

This is one of the *Dermal Armor* augmentations - listed in the *Skin Augmentations* section of the aug screen - and you will first need to unlock *Damage Reduction 2*.

It will cost a total of 4 Praxis points to obtain if you don't have any prerequisites:

- 2 to unlock *Dermal Armour* and *Damage Reduction 1*
- 1 to unlock *Damage Reduction 2*
- 1 to unlock *EMP Shielding*

Comment: @Josefvz if there are any handy crates nearby, you can simply chain them over the water by picking the previous crate up and dropping it in front of you to move forward. Not sure if this is what you meant by bypass or you meant that you had to find an alternate route.

Comment: @yx -- this is how I got behind the police station.

Comment: @yx. When i drop a crate on the electricity it bursts.

Comment: @yx. I just sprinted and jumped over the electricty behind the police station... you only have to get half way to get the switch and your health regenerates. Save 4 praxis points and sprint

Comment: @Josefvz Damageable crates will be instantly destroyed by electricity, but heavier crates or barrels won't be. Just make sure you don't topple them and fall right into the electricity.

Comment: @Shadur AHA! Thaks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 4):

[Yx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3917/yx) comment would deserve to become an answer: using heavy crates (not the destructible ones) is way faster and easier than getting the EMP Shielding augmentation (requiring XP).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a spender on EMP where I'll almost never use it....

Either I try to scavenge for a new path and find the voltage switch...

Or I get 2 light crates, jump on one, get the other infront and repeat.... slow, but definitely worth it at the end....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're at those tunnels in Panchaea. You can walk across the pipes to avoid the electricity. At the first crossing, you have a few breakable crates to the right. Instead of going right, go forward, and you should see a vent. If you carefully edge over towards the crates in front of it, you should be able to pick them up in order to get to the vent. You can switch off the electricity completely if you follow the vent. Watch out for the mine, though.